# Why do i have this page error while trying to download a file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Hi im having an error while trying to download an uploaded file. Im using laravel 7. The error is 404 page not found and it might be because the directory do not match.

This is my store method in my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){

      $detalleTicket = new DetalleTicket();

      if($request->file('file')){
         $file = $request->file('file');
         $filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
         $request->file->move('storage/', $filename);
         $detalleTicket->file = $filename;
       }      
       

       $detalleTicket->save();
       Session::flash('success');
       return redirect()->route('detalles-tickets.view');
   }
```

This is my download method in my controller:

```
public function download($file){
    return response()->download('storage/'.$file);
}
```

My directories are public->storage->(each file)

This is my route in web.php:

```
Route::get('/download/{file}', 'Backend\DetalleTicketController@download')->name('detalles-tickets.download');
```

And this is my dowload button:

```
<a title="Download" id="download" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                                        href="/detalles-tickets/download/{{ $detalleTicket->file }}"><i
                                        class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```

Does anyone knows why as is click on the button i get 404 page not found?

Comment: Because you're referencing the name as the actual url. e.g. the real URL is `/download/$file` not `/detalle-ticket/download/$file` you can find your routes with `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @MichaelMano i know but in my route list it appears "detalles-tickets/download/{file} "   So i change it to detalles-tickets/download/{{$detalleTicket->file}}"  and still have the same error.

Comment: What if you use the name. `href="{{ route('detalles-tickets.download', ['file' => $detalleTicket->file])  }}`

Comment: if id to that i get thist error: Missing required parameters for [Route: detalles-tickets.download] [URI: detalles-tickets/download/{file}]. (View: C:\Users\Mateo\OneDrive\Desktop\AXIS\globaltec-vuepanel-master\globaltec-vuepanel-master\resources\views\backend\detalle_ticket\view-detalle-ticket.blade.php)  @MichaelMano

Comment: Then my guess is that `$detalleTicket->file` is null.

Comment: @MichaelMano i edited my question and added more information because it seems that its bringing null to $detalleTicket->file but in my db the path is being stored.

Comment: its a different question now mang. may as well start one up since it has nothing to do with routes, also... remember to always debug your objects. would have saved this issue by doing a simple `dd($detalleTicket)`

Answer (score 1):

```
@if($detalleTicket->file)
<a
    title="Download"
    id="download"
    class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
    href="{{ route('detalles-tickets.download', ['file' => $detalleTicket->file]) }}">
    <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
</a>
@endif
```